# ext.js DateTimeFilter or TimeFilter, does any of those exist?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime, extjs, ext.net

I am looking for either a DateTimeFilter or a TimeFilter to add to my GridPanel in my ext.js/ext.net application and I can't seem to find one anywhere in the library. I would appreciate some help locating this feature as I would like to use it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Anyone? I have a requirement to filter the grid by time and I would appreciate help getting this done.

Answer (score 0):

take alook at this example

[GridPanel with Local Filtering](http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Plugins/GridFilters_Local/)